# How to save set of files from streaming sources

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, streaming

I would like to download and save a set of podcasts from SoundCloud. My list consists of dozens of records. I know URL (HTTPS protocol) of every single podcast and want to save each of them automatically into a separate file (I want to get a local set of sound files in the end). How, if at all, is it possible to do so?

So far I tried:

- VLC - I couldn’t force app to save every single podcast to independent file and was able to get one file consisting one record only. VLC was going to overwrite every previously saved podcast with a new one.
- Audacity - I was able to capture a stream (using VLC, I’ve made a playlist consisting of all URLs and started to stream) and recorded it. The problem is that all podcasts were put into one big file instead of separate files.
- OBS - the same as above

Any help will be appreciated. 
Regards

Comment: Can you give an example of a couple of URLs.

Comment: Here you have it:

`https://soundcloud.com/wydawnictwowam/jak-nie-zmarnowac-wakacji-i-zyc-na-100-mamy-na-to-sposob?in=wydawnictwowam/sets/szkola-uwaznosci`


`https://soundcloud.com/wydawnictwowam/01-jedna-z-najwa-niejszych?in=wydawnictwowam/sets/szkola-uwaznosci`


`https://soundcloud.com/wydawnictwowam/01-medytacja-to-nie-tylko-joga?in=wydawnictwowam/sets/szkola-uwaznosci`


`https://soundcloud.com/wydawnictwowam/01-patrzysz-ale-czy-widzisz-cwiczenie?in=wydawnictwowam/sets/szkola-uwaznosci`

Answer (score 1):

I remark that your URLs are not of the audio/video sources, but rather of the page
containing the player code.
I have tried to isolate the audio URLs, but this site seems to serve the video
in sections of 5 seconds, and not with just one URL.
Therefore you need a video downloader that can extract audio/video from the
player page itself.

One such video downloader, which may also accept a list of URLs in the format of a
playlist, is
[YouTube Video Downloader](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_downloader/).
I have not used it, so do not know how to construct such a playlist,
but it is one possible solution.

Another possibility is
[JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/)
which can download several files at once, but you will need to check if that
works with a list.

Try both products first with just one URL, to check that they can capture from this
website.